# Computing plane waves with the magnitude constant to 1

Tags: plotting, complex

I have a question. In regards with the given computation,

```
u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}];
{Plot3D[Re[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], 
     Plot3D[Im[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      ColorFunction -> Hue]}
{Plot3D[Abs[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[Arg[u0[r, phi]], {r, 0, 4}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All]}
```

which is in Cartesian coordinates, the magnitude of the series for the plane wave must be constant 1. How do I set this in the given code?

Thanks

Comment: What is the " magnitude of the series" ?

Comment: The magnitude of the sum.

Comment: u[r_, phi_] := u0[r,phi]/Abs[u0[r,phi]]

Comment: Thank you! Trying this. It is of the form u/|u| for a vector, right?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Yes it is of the form u/|u|